# "Hierarchical Select" alternate module for Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-8

I am currently migrating from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8, and we do not find the contributed module "Hierarchical Select" available, and I would ask if anyone knows an alternative module in Drupal 8 offering similar functionality.

Thank you in advance for the help/guidance you can lend me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading already? wow, ambitious.
Anyway..
The [Client-side hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) module seems to have a Drupal 8 branch and is the only hierarchy select module I can find that does.
I think it is superior too as afaik it does not require ajax requests.

Comment: _Client-Side Hierarchical Select_ can be very slow with large taxonomies when the form loads, since it loads the whole taxonomy (and filters it client-side, hence the name).